# Strange result from mutual reference in C++ macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

string TRUE = "true";
string FALSE = "false";

#define TRUE FALSE
#define FALSE TRUE

int main()
{
    cout << TRUE << endl;
    cout << FALSE << endl;
}
```

Compiled using GCC 4.9.2, the above code outputs:

```
true
false
```

What is the logic behind the produced output? I expected "false\ntrue\n" or even "false\nfalse\n", but I cannot find the reasoning behind this actual output.

How does the pair of #defines work in this case?

Comment: Have you looked at the preprocessor output? (-E)

Comment: Just did that. The output is exactly the code above, minus both #defines.

Comment: Exactly, and if you remove 1 of the defines, you'll see a change. I'm not sure so I won't post this as an answer, but my best guess is that, after the PP substitutes the first macro, it checks if the result is a macro, which it is. It then substitutes again, which gets you back where you started. To avoid infinite recursion in the PP, this is where it stops.

Comment: Of course, if you're writing *real* C++, instead of `#define` you would use `const` and would write `const string TRUE = FALSE; const string FALSE = TRUE;` and then the compiler would scream about redefinition. :)

Comment: Hopefully the message people get from reading this question and its answers is "Whoa, I really shouldn't be doing this!"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is described in [cpp.rescan]/1-2:

> #### 16.3.4 Rescanning and further replacement
>
> 1. After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and `#` and `##` processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. Then the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.
> 2. If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file's preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. **Furthermore, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced.** These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

(Emphasis mine)

So: When `TRUE` is encountered in the code, it is replaced with `FALSE`. The sequence is rescanned, `FALSE` is replaced with `TRUE`. The sequence is rescanned, `TRUE` is found but no longer eligible for replacement, and so it stays. The same applies for the expansion of `FALSE` (with swapped identifiers).

Comment: I see. So this is a standard and expected behavior, rather than undefined one. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 8):

Macros cannot be recursive: if a macro directly on indirectly expands to include its own name, that second occurrence will not be expanded any more. So in your case, the following expansions happen:

Input:

```
cout << TRUE << endl;
```

`TRUE` is a macro, it's expanded:

```
cout << FALSE << endl;
```

Expanded text re-scanned for macros, `FALSE` is found and expanded:

```
cout << TRUE << endl;
```

Expanded text re-scanned for macros, `TRUE` is found; but it was already expanded once, so nothing happens and it stays as `TRUE` for subsequent compilation (which then finds the global variable).